# Symfony 3 - Error on login with plaintext password

Tags: rest, symfony

I'am creating and API wth symfony, i have to use a database with plaintext password.

When i send a POST to /login_check with
_username : Username
_password : GoodPassword

I dont have problem, it works.

If i send :
But if i send :
_username0 : Username
_password : GoodPassword
I have a credential error : It's good

But if i send :
_username : Username
_password0 : GoodPassword

I have this error :
Warning: hash_equals(): Expected user_string to be a string, null given

I dont see where is the verification if all fields are in the form, can you help me ? (if a change password form plaintext to bcrypt, i have the crednetial error as i want)

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I really don't understand your question, can you be more clear about it?

Comment: If you dont send password to login_check, i get errror 500 instead of invald a BadCredentialsException

Answer (score 1):

Your post fields must have the same name than the one in `security.yml`. By default their name must be _username and _password, but you can change their name in your `security.yml` file:

```
security:
    firewalls:
      main:
        form_login:
          username_parameter: _username
          password_parameter: _password
```

More information on documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#username-parameter

Comment: I change the fields name in my security.yml:
                username_parameter: username
                password_parameter: password

Even if i use default name, i have the same problem.